# Nested Array to single array with subsets/tuples

Tags: python, dataformat

So I have data in an array in this format:

```
[[x_1,y_1],...,[x_n,y_n]]
```

and I need it in this format:

```
[(x_1,y_2),...,(x_n,y_n)]
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple call to [`tuple()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple) would suffice here.

```
>>> testList = [[1, 2], [1, 3]]
>>> [tuple(elem) for elem in testList]
[(1, 2), (1, 3)]
```

Or if you're looking to do it with `map`, then, do

```
>>> map(tuple, testList)
[(1, 2), (1, 3)]
```